# Jxls2 dynamic columns

Tags: java, excel, jxls

Currently, i have a List<MyClass> would like to display and repeat over columns.

```
    Class MyClass {
       String attr1;
       String attr2;
       String attr3;
    }
```

In Jxls 1.0.6, it could be defined by

```
    B1 -- <jx:forEach items="${myList}" var="m">
    C1 -- ${m.attr1}
    D1 -- ${m.attr2}
    E1 -- ${m.attr3}
    F1 -- </jx:forEach>
```

As of the performance issue, I am going to upgrade to Jxls 2.2.3.

In [this](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/each_command.html), I see there is an option of "direction" for a each command. So, I set the comment field in A1 as follows.

```
    jx:each(items="myList" var="m" lastCell="C1" area="A1:C1" direction=EachCommand.Direction.RIGHT)
```

and input these for the columns

```
    A1 -- ${m.attr1}
    B1 -- ${m.attr2}
    C1 -- ${m.attr3}
```

However, the output of the excel is


A1 B1 C1
X  X  X
X  X  X
X  X  X
....

and my exception is display like


A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 G1 H1 I1 J1
X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X ......

Is there any way to do it by the excel comment field and how to do if yes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Upgrade to jxls-2.2.4 (it was just released)
2. Use the following syntax to specify RIGHT direction for [Each-command](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/each_command.html)

   jx:each(items="myList" var="m" lastCell="C1" area="A1:C1" direction="RIGHT")

Comment: Thanks! It works. Further question.... If there is a "fixed column" in the right hand side.
e.g. (fixed columns) (dynamic columns) (fixed columns)
Is it supported?

Comment: No special processing is implemented for this case. So it will depend on how POI handles this. You should try it and see. If there is something you would like to be implemented raise a request in jxls issue tracker.